# Texlive dummy *.rpm package

Tags: linux, r, rpm

I installed Texlive 2013 on a Fedora 19 machine via the texlive homepage and not via the package manager. I use this option because I’m working with LuaLaTeX extensively and need the latest biblatex- and biber- packages for some of my documents. However, I also need R to be working on my machine. But as R is depending on a bunch of texlive packages and the package manager is not aware that Texlive 2013 is already installed, R will install texlive again which will lead to problems.

Hence, I want to make the package manager aware that Texlive 2013 is already installed. The obvious solution would be to create a dummy package. I’ve googled for solutions on how to exactly do this for some weeks now but as far as I can see there is no good explanation on how to do this for *.rpm based distributions out there. Maybe someone here can help.

My idea:
Create a dummy Texlive package which tells the package manager that texlive is already installed. The dummy package should tell the package manager that texlive-scheme-full is installed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your version of texlive on the path?

Comment: Yes, it is. I put it in .bash_profile via PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-linux export PATH.

Comment: Instead of making a dummy package, have you considered instead downloading the RPM source package and tweaking the `spec` file to build the latest? Fedora Rawhide shows a [version of Texlive 2013](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/source/SRPMS/t/texlive-2013-0.5.20130608_r30832.fc20.src.rpm) that's less than two weeks old.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks Aaron. I will look into this right now!